# Why does this statement add a character at the end of collection?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```
    ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
    strings.add("h");
    strings.add("e");
    strings.add("l");
    strings.add("l");
    strings.add("o");
```

The next statement is `strings.add(strings.remove(strings.size()-1)+"C");`

Then the output result is [h,e,l,l,oC],

So I want to know why the `strings.add(strings.remove(strings.size()-1)+"C")`got this result,

Comment: not sure why the votes to close for the question being unclear.

Comment: What part of that statement don't you understand?

Comment: Please explain what about the result is unexpected. Also, it's good to consult documentation before asking a question. It will help you to have higher quality questions and to perhaps even answer your own questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strings.remove(strings.size()-1)` returns "o" because `ArrayList.remove` returns the element that is removed. "o" is then concatenated with "C" creating "oC" which is added to the end of the `ArrayList`

You can think about `strings.add(strings.remove(strings.size()-1)+"C");` as being equivalent to:

```
String s = strings.remove(strings.size()-1);
// s is now equal to "o"
// strings is equal to ["h", "e", "l", "l"]
s += "C";
// s is now equal to "oC"
strings.add(s);
// strings is equal to ["h", "e", "l", "l", "oC"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

`strings.remove()` 
[returns the removed element to the calling place.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int))

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

In this case it returns 'o'. Then you concatenated it with 'C'.
Result is "oC"

Your last statement is adding this "oC" to `strings` arraylist.

Comment: How does this answer differ from the up-voted answer?

Comment: They were both answered around the same time. FGITW FTW

Comment: @Michael I was on my mobile, so I took bit time time type it, while the above answer had already appeared.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand now.